# kryptonDataGridView.CellBorderStyle not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, krypton-toolkit

If I have a normal DataGridView and I want to show only the horizontal lines, I apply the following code:

```
dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
```

Using the UI template Krypton for WinFroms, it is not working for me. I use:

```
kryptonDataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
```

And the lines still appear!

Did anyone come across this problem and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I hope you can still find this useful:

**Why your code doesn't work:**

Well, KryptonDataGridView inherits from the DataGridView WinForms control, and by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton/blob/master/Source/Krypton%20Components/ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit/Controls%20Toolkit/KryptonDataGridView.cs#L283), you'll find that `KryptonDataGridView.CellBorderStyle` simply gets or sets the value of `base.CellBorderStyle` which are not the same borders displayed by KryptonDataGridView.

A lot of the inherited properties doesn't have an effect on Krypton controls (the `Font` property, for example). But in most cases, Krypton provides an alternative *(with more features usually)*.

**Solution:**

To replicate the behavior of `DataGridView.CellBorderStyle`, with KryptonDataGridView, you should use the `DataCell.Border.DrawBorders` property of the appropriate `State`:

```
using ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit;
//

kryptonDataGridView1.StateCommon.DataCell.Border.DrawBorders =
    PaletteDrawBorders.TopBottom;
```

**Result:**

[image: KryptonDataGridView]

Hope that helps.